# How to filter out objects in an array in angular?

Tags: angular

I have an array empData of json objects as below -

```
[
{
 "EmployeeID": "ABC",
 "Department": "IT",

},
{
 "EmployeeID": "PQR",
 "Department": "IT",
},
{
 "EmployeeID": "IJK",
 "Department": "Legal",
},
{
 "EmployeeID": "LMN",
 "Department": "Legal",
},
 .
 .
 .
]
```

I want to store all the employees with the same department in a separate array. The department value comes from an HTML form which on change calls a function to perform this action.

HTML -

```
<select class="form-control" (change)="getEmployees($event.target.value)">
```

In TS -

```
    empArr[];
    input;
    getEmployees(emp){

    this.input = emp;
    for (let x of this.empData) {

    if (this.input == x.Department) {

        this.empArr.push(this.empData.find(x => x.Department== this.input)); 
        console.log(this.empArr)
      }

    }
```

I am facing two issues -

1. empArr gets created the number of times there is department in the array instead of one array containing the total number of objects satisfying the condition.
2. It picks only the first value that contains the input department and lists it the total number of times it exists instead of picking unique object in each iteration.

Can anyone please help me solve this?

Thanks !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just apply filter, it returns a new array:

```
empArr=this.empData.filter(emp => emp.Department === this.input)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can filter each empData that has same department as input, this way

```
this.empData.filter(emp => emp.Department == this.input)
            .forEach(filteredData => this.empArr.push(filteredData);
```

Comment: I got an error - "Argument of type 'any' is not assignable to parameter of type 'never' ", after which I changed the type of empArr as empArr : any[] = []; It returned an empty array.
However, it works perfectly if I just use - this.empData.filter(emp => emp.Department == this.input) and assign it to empArr

Comment: check this to know what you maybe doing wrong. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-jhzf7h

Comment: Hi

Thank you for sharing this !
Actually, this is a sample data that I posted. In my original code I wanted to filter out objects in a json array returned by an API. 
In your code, you have assigned empArr as empArr : any[] = [] ; whereas in my code it is assigned as empArr : any; because otherwise it throws the error - "The 'Object' type is assignable to very few other types". Maybe it is because empArr returned from the API is already of type array? 
I am very new to Angular, so I am not able to figure out why it throws an error if I use forEach . Maybe you could throw some light.